# problem with the diagrams of the rational unfied process

Tags: uml, rational-unified-process

I want to verify that i correctly understand the rational unified process.

My understanding is:

1. For the requirements specification activity, i have to design the use case diagram (a general one), the class diagram (classes, attributes, relations), and a general sequence diagram.
2. For the analysis activity, i have to design a detailed use case, the sequence diagram (using control, view and model classes), the analysis class diagram, the collaboration diagram
3. For the conception diagram, i have to design the class diagram and the deploiement diagram

is that correct please?

for my questions:

1. When can i use the activity and the state-transition diagrams?
2. Is it correct to first design a class diagram in the requirement acquisition phase?
3. In the implementation phase, which diagrams do i have to use? Or do you only have to generate code from some diagrams?

thank you a lot !!

Comment: thank you Wolfgang for corrections.

Comment: Although this question is old. it seems appropriate to comment so that others aren't led astray. "The [Rational Unified Process (RUP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Unified_Process) is **not a single concrete prescriptive process**, but rather an adaptable process framework, intended to be tailored."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are right.

1. ADs are used to illustrate scenarios from a use case. State transitions are usually created for classes. The can be used in code generation.
2. Not really. To sketch a class diagram of your solution you need a rough idea how that could look like. Just taking it from requirements works only for simple systems. You need to go through the use cases first to settle a usable construct.
3. To implement a system some class diagrams are essential. SDs help the coder to see how the classes collaborate. You can not generate code from that. Only code stubs from classes.

Comment: FWIW: RUP is far too complex. Google for ICONIX. They have a much leaner approach which got me going in the beginning (some decades ago).

Comment: thank you a lot  Thomas. i have to use RUP to design my information system. except the class diagram, we can not generate the code of the implementation phase from other diagrams?

Comment: As stated the classes will deliver a scaffold (that is attributes and function headers). Statemachines can also be translated to code directly. But anything else must be done by a coder.

Comment: @ThomasKilian what about `fUML` and activity diagrams?

Comment: @xmojmr I haven't seen any break-through with executable UML so far. From my POV there should be a break between modeling and implementation. Putting the implementation part into the modelers hand will not yield better products since they are two different skills. And having them in one person is a rare gift.